# Can Record Trigger Flow throw error message like Validation rule?

Tags: recordtriggeredflow

There is a Record Triggered flow activated for "Account Territory Product" object to restrict on creation of duplicate records of this object. Can someone please help me in knowin how this error message is showing up?

Thanks,
Vidya
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get this kind of error without code. Either there is a [Duplicate Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) that matches on "test field", or there is a unique index on the field "test field" itself. I'd check the field first in Setup | Object Manager | <object-name> | Fields & Relationships | <field-name>, and see if the Unique property is set. If it's not, check Setup | Data | Duplicate Management | Duplicate Rules, see which rules are active, and check out their behavior (the Block action could cause an error like this). You may need to configure your rules, the unique index, or the Flow, as appropriate, in order to solve this problem, depending on what the desired outcome is. You could also write an Apex Invocable Method to perform the DML with the DuplicateRuleHeader set to ignore duplicates if Duplicate Rules are the problem, or you might need to use an "upsert" DML operation to allow insert/update.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcox for the information. "test field" is present in the object which is set as Unique.